# Issue in ERC721 token transfer to contract address

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, erc-721

I am using ERC721 implementation for NFT tokens.

I am testing the transfer functionalities in ERC721.

```
 `transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId)`    
 `safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId)`
 `safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data)`
```

I have tried the token transfer scenario with `_to` address as account address.

I am trying to do the token transfer scenarios with `_to` address as contract address.

I have written a receiver contract for testing the functionality.

```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

  import "./standard/ERC721TokenReceiver.sol";

  contract ValidReceiver is ERC721TokenReceiver {

      event  LOGTokenFallBack(address from,bytes4 value);

      function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external returns(bytes4 value) {
            emit LOGTokenFallBack(_from, bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)")));
            return 0x150b7a02;

     } 
}
```

Updated the `safeTranferFrom` functionality also as follows:-

```
   function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) public  {
    transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);

    //Get size of "_to" address, if 0 it's a wallet
    uint32 size;
    assembly {
        size := extcodesize(_to)
    }
    if(size > 0){
       ERC721TokenReceiver receiver = ERC721TokenReceiver(_to);
       require(receiver.onERC721Received(msg.sender,_from,_tokenId,data) == bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)")));

    }
```

It seems to be that the transfer gets reverted.

I have updated the `ERC721TokenReceiver` by removing the return type as follows.

```
   function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external ;
```

And updated `ValidReceiver` as follows.

contract ValidReceiver is ERC721TokenReceiver {

```
      event  LOGTokenFallBack(address from,bytes4 value);

      function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external  {
            emit LOGTokenFallBack(_from, bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)")));


     } 
}
```

And it seems to be a successful transfer by emitting the `LOGTokenFallBack` event.

I have tried various ways to do the transfer by return type in receiver contract.

Did anyone face the issue similar to the one mentioned?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There seems no issue with the contract or the implementation. Maybe the transfer fn at `transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);` reverts. I have tested the same contracts and it worked perfect, emitted events.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh   I have tried the same using mocha test scripts as well as using the truffle console. I am still facing the issue while calling the receiver contract function having return type. ```receiver.onERC721Received(msg.sender,_from,_tokenId,data)```.  This call gets reverted, and I didn't get the bytes value as response.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I have changed the return type to `bool` instead of `bytes`. And it has the same issue.It seems to be working,if I remove the return type from both my receiver interface and contract.

Answer (score 1):

Try our [official ERC721](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721) implementation. Here is also a working example described in our [test case](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/8795444961ed03f9787566c6501cb40fb82408ad/src/tests/tokens/nf-token.test.ts#L356). See also a link to the [ERC721 receiver mock](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/tests/mocks/nf-token-receiver-test-mock.sol) and a direct link to the [safeTransferFrom](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/8795444961ed03f9787566c6501cb40fb82408ad/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token.sol#L437) implementation.

Btw, things can become much simpler with the [0xcert Framework](https://github.com/0xcert/framework). It hides the complexity, you don't have to write Solidity at all, you just use Javascript methods.